# Need to convert char type column to date type

Tags: r, datetime, chr

I have a data.table with a column named 'Date' and type char and it looks like below. I need to convert this to date type column so that i can perform date operations.

```
Date
"10/11/2018"
"13/11/2013"
"22/11/2011"
"--"
"--"
"10/11/2018"
```

I tried this, but doesn't work

```
MyTable$Date <- as.POXISlt(MyTable$Date)
```

Comment: use lubridate::dmy(Date), you need to install lubridate library

Comment: lubridate isn't required, but is nice to use. Alternative is `as.Date("01/11/2018", "%d/%m/%Y")`. See https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @JonnyPhelps - I am getting this error as "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" for as.Date(MyTable$Date)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Using data.table I'd suggest the following:

```
library(data.table)

MyTable <- data.table(Date = c(
  "10/11/2018",
  "13/11/2013",
  "22/11/2011",
  "--",
  "--",
  "10/11/2018"
))

MyTable[, posixDate := as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

[image]

If you need to get rid of the NA rows use: `na.omit(MyTable)`